# qsort won't sort an array of integers

Tags: arrays, c, qsort

This is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int comp (const void *a, const void *b)
{
    int *s1 = (int *)a;
    int *s2 = (int *)b;

    return (s1 - s2);
}

int main() {
    int a[] = { 1, 2, 5, 3 };
    qsort(a, 4, sizeof(a), comp);
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeof(a) / sizeof(a[0]); i++) {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
}
```

I am using `qsort()` to sort my array ascending, but unfortunately, nothing happens. The array elements stay at their same positions. I tried printing messages whenever the `comp()` function is called, and it is called properly. The problem is, elements are not changed.

What could be the problem?

Comment: You're subtracting pointers, not integers. Deference the pointer to get the actual value.

Comment: It will nicely sort these by location in the memory :) Oh, well, they are already sorted by that...

Comment: @ChristopherMoore you mean `return (*s1 - *s2)`?

Comment: By the way, this is a dangerous function. It can overflow `int`. You better use comparison and return `+/-1`  or `0` depending on it.

Comment: The `qsort()` argument `sizeof(a)` is wrong too, it should be `sizeof a[0]` (the size of each element).

Comment: @EugeneSh. can you provide me some sort of code snippet?

Comment: There is a minor inconsistency too: you pass `4` to `qsort()` as the number of elements but use `sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])` for the loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're subtracting pointers, not integers. Deference the pointer to get the actual value.

That could mean doing `return (*s1 - *s2)` as you said. However, as Eugene Sh. mentions, this can overflow `int`. So instead compare `*s1` and `*s2` and return `1`, `-1`, or, `0` accordingly. Weather Vane also mentions you're passing the wrong size value. You should be passing the number of elements and the size of each element to the 2nd and 3rd parameters respectively.
So `qsort(a, sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]), sizeof(a[0]), comp);`

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int comp (const void * a, const void * b)
{
    int *s1 = (int *)a;
    int *s2 = (int *)b;

    if(*s1 > *s2) {
        return 1;
    }
    else if(*s1 == *s2) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        return -1;
    }
}

int main() {
    int a[] = {1, 2, 5, 3};
    qsort(a, sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]), sizeof(a[0]), comp);
    for (int i = 0; i<sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0]); i++) {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Minor: Code could drop some `()`: `sizeof(a)/sizeof(a[0])` --> `sizeof a/sizeof a[0]` and `int i = 0` better as `size_t i = 0`